# Combine Multiple Foreach Results To One Variable String

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have multiple foreach loops below, and I'm trying to join one set of data inside one foreach, with another set of data in the other foreach, so I can create one main variable to post anywhere on my page with these values. I thought the way I had it setup below would work, but it's not. Any suggestions?

The variables I have setup right now, with the data I need to collect is `$variable`

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    $sections[$row['section_id']][$row['question_id']] = $row;
}

foreach ($sections as $key => $section) {
    $question_keys = array_keys($section);
    foreach ($question_keys as $question_key) {
        if ($section[$question_key]["selection"] == 2) {

        } else {
            $variable .= '<div id="section-title">'.$section_details[$key].'</div>';
            foreach ($section as $key => $questions) {
                $variable .= '<div id="section-desc">
                <div>'.$question_details[$key]["title"].'</div>
                <div>'.$question_details[$key]["desc"].'</div>       
                <div>'.$selection_details[$questions["selection"]].'</div></div>';
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

The first `$variable` assigned is a section. Sections nest questions. There can be multiple sections nesting questions that belong to it. The second `$variable` assigned is questions nested underneath the section. Questions can be multiple.

**Array output at** `$section` **level**

```
Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [assessment_selection_id] => 97
        [assessment_id] => 32
        [section_id] => 2
        [question_id] => 2
        [selection] => 1
        [timestamp] => 1368183565
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [assessment_selection_id] => 98
        [assessment_id] => 32
        [section_id] => 2
        [question_id] => 1
        [selection] => 3
        [timestamp] => 1368183580
    )

)
```

Comment: Can you `print_r();` your array here???

Comment: Also, please show an example of desired output and output you have now.

Comment: @elavarasanlee I added the array above.

Comment: So, you are saying that you have sections with questions related to it. And want to display section title and than questions under that section, right?

Comment: @ChristianPage:pardon if am wrong.i understand it like u want to make an array with elements of other two arrays by comparing certain values.if yes, then you will have to write a foreach inside a foreach

Comment: Yes you are correct. Where would you put the new foreach? Post it in an answer.

Comment: @ChristianPage : `$section_details` and `$selection_details` are they two different arrays???

Comment: yes, but they have nothing to do with this. They hold information on another page. They are static array's.

Answer (score -1):

First of all define $variable outside the foreach loop.
then there is issue looks inside the structure of string which you are assigning to the the $variable as it contains some html elements, might be they are not getting seen on browser.

Comment: Serialize is for serialization, not to convert PHP objects into HTML representation.

Comment: I know what serialization is, and it's not called for what I'm needing.